# Bucle While/loop/do JavaScript que termine la ejecución cuando el usuario haga clic en la pantalla

Tags: javascript

Necesito generar un bucle infinito que termine cuando el usuario haga clic en la pagina pare el bucle.

¿Es posible hacerlo?

La idea, es que cuando yo recibe una notificación de un usuario, el navegador me lo notifique (en la parte superior del navegador).

```
socket.on('receivedMessage' , function (msg){
    document.title = "Tienes mensajes nuevos";
  });
```

Entonces yo quiero hacer que el titulo "parpade", poniendo el mensaje : "Tienes mensajes nuevos" y después de X segundos, "nombre de la pagina", y después de X segundos, "Tienes mensajes nuevos".

había pensado implementarlo con `setTimeout`

```
      var titleNotificacion;
  alertFunc();
  function alertFunc() {
    titleNotificacion = setTimeout(function() {
       document.title = "Tienes mensajes nuevos";

       alertFunc2();
     }, 2000);
  }
  function alertFunc2() {
    titleNotificacion = setTimeout(function() {
       document.title = "Nombre-de-la-pagina";

       alertFunc();
     }, 2000);


  }
```

Esto me lo hace correctamente! Parpadea el mensaje!!, pero cuando entro a la pagina, o cuando hago focus sobre ella, no para nunca el `setTimeout`, porque he realizado un bucle de funciones.

Luego, he estado pensando, y me merecía más la pena hacer un bucle infinito con estos dos mensajes, llamando las funciones `setTimeout` y decir que pare la ejecución del bucle, cuando el usuario haga un `window.click`.

> Nuevo código modificado tras las ultimas aportaciones

```
socket.on('receivedMessage' , function (msg){

      window.DoInfiniteLoop = true;
      InfiniteLoop();
      function InfiniteLoop() {
      if( window.DoInfiniteLoop  === true)
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.title = "nombre-pagina";
          document.onclick  = function() {
            document.title = "nombre-pagina"; window.DoInfiniteLoop = false;
            InfiniteLoop();
          }
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
          document.title = "Tienes mensajes nuevos";
          document.onclick  = function() {
            document.title = "nombre-pagina"; window.DoInfiniteLoop = false;
            InfiniteLoop();
          }
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout( InfiniteLoop, 3000 );
      }
  });
```

Me hace el "parpadeo" correctamente. Pero cuando hago clic en el navegador, no para el bucle!, en el momento de hacer clic, si me hace caso, pero luego sigue con el curso del bucle.

Comment: Hacer un bucle infinito puede volver el navegador inestable y dejarlo tieso. Si puedes explicar un poco que funcionalidad necesitas y que has intentado estamos encantados de ayudarte

Comment: edito mi pregunta entonces, gracias por el interes

Comment: Ya esta editado. Espero que se me entienda

Comment: @PictorGames respuesta editada. ¡ Me ha pillado la caida del sitio !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript utiliza un único hilo para su ejecución, así que, si haces un bucle infinito *a lo bruto*, tipo:

```
while( true ) { }
```

dejarás el navegador *congelado*. Los posibles eventos pendientes se acumularán en la cola de eventos, sin que nadie los procese.

Es necesario *dejarle respirar*, para que procese la cola. Una forma simple de hacerlo es:

```
functión InfiniteLoop( ) {
  if( window.DoInfiniteLoop )
    setTimeout( InfiniteLoop, 0 );
}
```

Con esto, lo que hacemos es añadir continuamente un evento a la cola, que será procesado cuando le llegue el turno. Observa que siempre *salimos* de la función `InfiniteLoop( )`. Es en estas salidas en las que el navegador procesa la cola de eventos.

Para iniciar el bucle:

```
window.DoInfiniteLoop = true;
window.DoInfiniteLoop( );
```

Y, cuando quieras detenerlo, solo has de hacer:

```
window.DoInfiniteLoop = false;
```

Esto lo puedes hacer desde cualquier *manejador de eventos* que tengas activado.

Mas información sobre el [Modelo de concurrencia y loop de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

**EDITO**

El siguiente código cambiará el título. **No lo he probado**, pero, salvo modificaciones mínimas, debería funcionar.

```
function ShowMessages( ) {
  if( InfiniteLoop ) {
    document.title = InfiniteLoop;
    setTimeout( RestoreTitle, 1000 );
  }
}

function RestoreTitle( ) {
  document.title = 'Título original';

  if( InfiniteLoop )
    setTimeout( ShowMessages, 100 );
}

socket.on('receivedMessage' , function( msg ) {
  ... // Código que haga lo que queramos hacer.
  InfiniteLoop = 'Otro título'; // EL MENSAJE QUE QUIERAS PONER.
                                // NO PUEDE SER LA CADENA VACÍA.
  setTimeout( ShowMessages, 0 );
}

window.onclick = function( ) {
  InfiniteLoop = false;
  RestoreTitle( );
}
```

Comment: Voy a intentar implementarlo. Muchas gracias! Si tengo algún problema o duda te lo comento

Comment: No me lo ha solucionado. Edito mi pregunta con el codigo

Comment: Gracias! todo correcto

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esto de una pregunta en ingles y cambiarlo a lo que necesites

[La pregunta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531927/stopping-a-recursive-function-call-onclick-button1-from-a-different-function-onc)

El codigo en si:

```js
var stopSliding = false;

$('#stop_button').click(function(){
 stopSliding = true;
});

$('#slide_button').click(function infiniteLoop(){
 if (stopSliding == true)
 {
  $('#top_message').stop();
  return;
 }  
 else
 {
  $('#top_message').hide().slideDown(2000);
  $('#top_message').slideUp(2000, infiniteLoop);
  return;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_message" style="display: none;"><h2>HELLO WORLD!</h2></div>
 <br />
 <input type="button" id="slide_button" value="Loop slide!" /><br />
 <input type="button" id="stop_button" value="STOP Loop slide!" /><br />
```

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, espero que se me entienda.

Comment: Pregunta modificada 2nda vez